# predefined custom field on registration page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, user-registration

What I want to do is, i have a professional theme (like elist from elegant theme) and in theme there are so many custom fields. I want to include those custom fields into my Wordpress custom registration page. For registration I use http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/

Answer (score 0):

Find `<div id=tab2_login"` and replace it with following code.Assuming you will change **CSS** and **JS** accordingly.

```
 <div id="tab2_login" class="tab_content_login" style="display:none;">
        <h3>Register for this site!</h3>
        <p>Sign up now for the good stuff.</p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="101" />
            </div>
            <div class="password">
                <label for="user_email"><?php _e('Your Email'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>" size="25" id="user_email" tabindex="102" />
            </div><!--New Field Here -->
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('New Field Name'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="new_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($new_field)); ?>" size="20" id="new_field" tabindex="103" />
            </div> <!--End of New Field -->
            <div class="login_fields">
                <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
                <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Sign up!'); ?>" class="user-submit" tabindex="103" />
                <?php $register = $_GET['register']; if($register == true) { echo '<p>Check your email for the password!</p>'; } ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?register=true" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Rohil I want to include some predefined WordPress custom fields on this form like elist has so many inbuilt custom field. I saw that you include a new_field in the form but I want the old theme default custom field there